# Auto fit all UICollectionViewCell from data source to screen without scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've an array of `UIColor`'s in my data source, what I'm trying to do is to fit all cells' size so they can all be seen on screen without scrolling.

I don't know how to do it, so far I've:

```
#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDataSource>

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.dataSource.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell
    UIColor *cellColor = (UIColor *)self.dataSource[indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = cellColor;

    for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            if ([[(UIImageView *)view image] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"V_BG.png"]]) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
    }

    if ([cellColor isEqual:self.existingColor]) {
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"V_BG.png"]];
        img.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
        img.center = cell.contentView.center;
        img.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:img];
    }

    return cell;
}

#pragma mark <UICollectionViewDelegate>

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:UIColorDidChangeNotification
                                                        object:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row]];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerRetro];
}

#pragma mark Collection view layout things

// Layout: Set cell size
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat fixSize = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width / 3) - 2;
    return CGSizeMake(fixSize, fixSize);
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 2;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: So you have a grid of colours to pick colours from ? A collection view by default won't scroll or have bounce if its content frames is smaller than the collection view's frame. Your color swatch is 30 by 30, so you can use a bit of maths to calculate how many 30x30 swatch you can fit on your target device's screen. e.g. iPhone 4 with 480 pixel height can fit 480 / 30 = 16 lots of 30x30 swatch, assuming each swatch is tightly packed together with no padding or margin.